# How to make a function to do preg_replace on an array?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm using this function to remove some variables from the url:

```
function removeqsvar($url, $varname) {

    return preg_replace('/([?&])'.$varname.'=[^&]+(&|$)/','$1',$url);
}
```

When using an array of variables, the function doesn't work, I need to be able to provide the function with an array of variables. How can I do that?

Comment: Which variable? `Join()` it into an alternatives expression if `$varname` is a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeqsvar($url, $varname) {
    if (is_array($url)) {
        $r = array();
        foreach ($url as $u) {
            array_push($r, preg_replace('/([?&])'.$varname.'=[^&]+(&|$)/','$1',$u));
        }
        return $r;
    }
    else {
        return preg_replace('/([?&])'.$varname.'=[^&]+(&|$)/','$1',$url);
    }
}
```

Comment: just make it recursive for it to work, if there is array in an array :P... but that would require another multidimensional array to return value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's not a multi-dimensional array, this should work:

```
function removeqsvar($array, $varname){
    foreach($array as $key => $val){
        $array[$key] = preg_replace('/([?&])'.$varname.'=[^&]+(&|$)/','$1', $val);
    }
    return $array;
}
```